# get Intent from specific class or Activity because PutExtras() from Intents not resolving

Tags: android

ok am having a funny problem here, scenario is like this:

Intent i of Activity "B" calls Activity "A" and the method in onCreate() of Activity "A" runs;

intent j of activity "B" calls Activity "A" and puts an "Int" extra which i can use to call a method in Activity "A"

intent x, y and z of TabActivity "C" calls Activity "A" and puts a "String" Extra in other to start a different method in Activity "A";

problem am having is that, regardless of what i put in the intent of Activity "C", the method from intent j keeps executing.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

                          fillData(); // intent i of Activity B

            HandleIntent(getIntent()); // other intents

    }

    public void HandleIntent(Intent intent){
        getIntent();

        if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){
    int priorityrequest = intent.getIntExtra("com.MyApp.PriorityRequestCode" PRIORITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        if(priorityrequest == 1){
            PSData(); //  from intent j of Activity B this keeps executing
        } 
 int homerequest = intent.getIntExtra("com.MyApp.HomeRequestCode", HOME_REQUEST_CODE);
         if(homerequest == 3){
             HomeData(); // doesn't execute keeps executing PSData();
         }
          }
    }

    public void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent){
        HandleIntent(getIntent());
        super.onNewIntent(newIntent);   
    }
```

From the code, PSData() keeps executing regardless of if i send another intent from another activity with the HOME_REQUEST_CODE. or is it possible to get Intent from a specific class or activity?...

Comment: I assume the String "action" is the null object?  I've never used getAction before.  Is that different from just putting a string "extra" in the intent?  Is it null when called from onCreate and not when called from onNewIntent, the other way around, or nothing like that?

Comment: its nothing like that, it actually executes when called from the activity. but if i try to call the method in onCreate() of Activity "A", it throws the exception. i tried using "putExtra" like i did in the previous code for all the intents, but then they started executing the method in onCreate(). i am not too sure about onNewIntent() being called at all.. have no idea what to do again.

Comment: i don't know if this will help, but i don't call startActivity() for all the intents. those that have the setAction() methods are called from a tabActivity to fill up tabs. so i don't know if that is the problem.

Comment: ok.. i have done some test and i will edit my question to a much better format.

Comment: have run out of ideas, please, anyone have anything i can try?.. thanks

Comment: anyone?..  am pretty stuck here. i don't know what to try anymore. no matter what i try,i can't seem to resolve the intents. it keeps calling the same intent from the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 
`intent.getIntExtra("com.MyApp.PriorityRequestCode" PRIORITY_REQUEST_CODE);` a comma is missing:
`intent.getIntExtra("com.MyApp.PriorityRequestCode", PRIORITY_REQUEST_CODE);`

is the default value of PRIORITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1?

Since you compare to a specific value and maybe you don't need a default value, you can try this sintax

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras != null){
    int priorityrequest = extras.getInt("com.MyApp.PriorityRequestCode");
    if(priorityrequest == 1){         
        PSData(); 
    }
    int homerequest = extras.getInt("com.MyApp.HomeRequestCode"); 
    if(homerequest == 3){          
        HomeData();
    }
}
```